# Scope of SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

Tags: sql-server

if I have `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` in one stored procedure to get rid of a warning, it only takes effects of that stored procedure and has no impact on other ones, which means in other stored procedures, the `ANSI_WARNINGS` is still on.
What if I want to turn it off for all stored procedures?
Why it is default on? How could I know that?

Do other settings(e.g., `NOCOUNT`) in sql server work the same way?

Thanks a lot.

It will be great if anybody can share articles about common characteristics of these settings with me.

Answer (score 4):

It's possibly worth point out that not only does it NOT affect other stored procedures, it only affects statements following the SET operation

e.g. run this and you will see that the option is turned off then on and then off again.

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    intvalue int NULL
) 
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL)
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
SELECT COUNT(intvalue) FROM test
-- (1 row(s) affected)
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SELECT COUNT(intvalue) FROM test
-- (1 row(s) affected)
-- Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
SELECT COUNT(intvalue) FROM test
-- (1 row(s) affected)
DROP TABLE test
```

Answer (score 2):

From BOL:

> SQL Server includes the ANSI_WARNINGS database option. This is
>   equivalent to SET ANSI_WARNINGS. When SET ANSI_WARNINGS is ON, errors
>   or warnings are raised in divide-by-zero, string too large for
>   database column, and other similar errors. When SET ANSI_WARNINGS is
>   OFF, these errors and warnings are not raised. The default value in
>   the model database for SET ANSI_WARNINGS is OFF. If not specified, the
>   setting of ANSI_WARNINGS applies. If SET ANSI_WARNINGS is OFF, SQL
>   Server uses the value of the is_ansi_warnings_on column in the
>   sys.databases catalog view.

You can read about it in BOL (F1 in Management Studio) or on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190368.aspx

NOCOUNT works the same.

Comment: I had similar questions and found that particular section impossible to read. I first thought it was the usual auto-German junk but after switching to English it got not be better. Are you saying you understand it? ,)