# SQL Server flags

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I'm writing a trigger that inside its implementation alters a flag as follows

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
```

What is the scope of this change? The trigger, transaction, connection, X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Scope of SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989051/scope-of-set-ansi-warnings-off).

Also, do note that the specification states that the syntax is to be deprecated http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx:

`In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will always be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.`

Comment: Testing if two variables are not equal \@old <> \@new takes 1 comparison. Testing it the way MS recommends - \@old <> \@new OR (\@old is not null and \@new is null) or (\@old is null and \@new is not null) is 10 comparisons. In a trigger doing this multiple times per row for batch loaded systems, the performance is noticeable.