# cursor execute command prematurely exits without error for long running stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc

Have a pyodbc script that is supposed to execute a stored procedure on an MSSQL server, but appears to be cutting out without error in the middle of running.

I have pyodbc that connects to a MSSQL (2012) server runs a stored procedure (that runs several other subordinate stored procedures) which normally lasts for about 45min, but when running via pyodbc it appears to exit after a certain amount of time (though never exactly consistent in how long) where it just quits without warning or error (*does not occur when running manually on the MSSQL server itself*, thus why I think having "SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF" is [fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6992641/8236733)). Adding debugging print statements to the subordinate stored procedures seems to confirm this: execution seems to simply end in the middle of running (usually after about 25-26min). The code looks like...

```py
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(f"DSN={CONFS['odbc_dsn']};"
                      f"DATABASE={'mydb'};"
                      f"UID={CONFS['username']};PWD={CONFS['password']};"
                      f"MultipleActiveResultSets=True;",
                      autocommit=True)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

print("\n\n\nRunning web reporting processes...")
stored_procs = [
    "mydb..some_initialization_stuff",
    "mydb..long_running_stored_proc"
]
cursor.commit()
for sp in stored_procs:
    print(f"\n\t[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Running stored procedure {sp}")
    cursor.execute(f"SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF; exec {sp}")
    # cursor.commit()
    print(f"\t[{datetime.datetime.now()}] stored procedure {sp} completed")
    # print(cursor.fetchall())
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

Anyone with more experience with pyodbc know what could be causing this? Any other information / specific debugging steps to improve this question?

Comment: After further debugging, found that using `cursor.execute(f"SET NOCOUNT ON; exec {sp}")` does not run into the same problem. Not quite sure why this would be. Any ideas as to why this works?

Comment: Look at your code. Do you see a problem waiting to be found? You should. Your connection should provide the context for your database queries. If you connect to the mydb database, then your queries should generally be using objects within that database. Change the database in your connection and the logic follows. Except here - where you used 3 part names (poorly I might add - don't assume a schema) for your stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

After asking question on the pyodbc [github issues page](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/714#issuecomment-591057894), basically the [reason is](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/827575/sql-server-does-not-finish-execution-of-a-large-batch-of-sql-statement)...

> When processing the results of a batch, **SQL Server fills the output buffer of the connection with the result sets that are created by the batch**. These result sets must be processed by the client application. If you are executing a large batch with multiple result sets, SQL Server **fills that output buffer until it hits an internal limit and cannot continue to process more result sets**. At that point, control returns to the client. When the client starts to consume the result sets, SQL Server starts to execute the batch again because there is now available memory in the output buffer.

You can either...

> Method 1: Flush all the output result sets...

or

> Method 2: Add the statement SET NOCOUNT ON to the beginning of your batch...

which is why using

```py
cursor.execute(f"SET NOCOUNT ON; exec {sp}")
```

worked for me.

(Not sure method 1 is an option in my case since we are only running a single large stored procedure (that calls other stored procedures) and not sure if there is a way to have the buffer flush in the middle of that, but if there is way please do let me know).

Answer (score 0):

Strip your stored procedure of any PRINT statements and SET NOCOUNT ON or the stored procedure might silently fail. This is not necessary if you are using the Microsoft non-ODBC driver.

SET NOCOUNT ON - Stops the message that shows the count of the number of rows affected by a Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure from being returned as part of the result set.
PRINT - Returns a user-defined message to the client.

If you are not able to change the stored procedure then add SET NOCOUNT ON to the cursor execute() the command: cursor.execute(f"SET NOCOUNT ON; exec {sp}")

Reason:
When processing the results of a batch, SQL Server fills the output buffer of the connection with the result sets that are created by the batch. These result sets must be processed by the client application. If you are executing a large batch with multiple result sets, SQL Server fills that output buffer until it hits an internal limit and cannot continue to process more result sets. At that point, control returns to the client. When the client starts to consume the result sets, SQL Server starts to execute the batch again because there is now available memory in the output buffer.